# Как стилизовать Input без библиотеки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет!

Хочу сделать такой Input

http://codepen.io/ilwcss/pen/tAgqH

```css
@import "nib"

body
  padding:40px
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue"

.input-wrapper
  position:relative
  line-height:14px
  margin:0 10px
  display:inline-block

label
  color:#bbb
  font-size:11px
  text-transform:uppercase
  position:absolute
  z-index:2
  left:20px
  top:14px
  padding:0 2px
  pointer-events:none
  background:white
  transition:transform 100ms ease
  transform:translateY(-20px)

input 
  font-size:13px
  color:#555
  outline:none
  border:1px solid #bbb
  padding:10px 20px
  border-radius:20px
  position:relative

  &:invalid + label
    transform:translateY(0)
    
  &:focus
    border-color:#2b96f1

    & + label
      color:#2b96f1
      transform:translateY(-20px)
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="user" required>
  <label for="user">user name</label>
</div>
  
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="password" required>
  <label for="user">password</label>
</div>
```

но в нем используются библиотеки и препроцессор.

Как выдернуть нужные данные из библиотеки и сделать обычный файл CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Утро вечера мудренее... Вот вам рабочий вариант.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container input {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #59d;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.container input+span {
  position: absolute;
  left: .5em;
  top: calc(.5em - 2px);
  color: #bbb;
  z-index: -10;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  transition: .2s;
}

.container input:focus+span,
.container input:valid+span {
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" value="" required><span>Name</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все сделал с вашей помощью! В принципе вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 5):

Не понимаю, о какой библиотеке вы говорите (пример ниже я просто скопировал и вставил, вроде бы это обычный css и никаких библиотек я здесь не вижу). Если вы имеете ввиду nib, то это не совсем библиотека, скорее расширение стилуса для придания кроссбраузерности.

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
label {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 20px;
  top: 14px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 100ms ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 100ms ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 100ms ease;
  transition: transform 100ms ease;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
input {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #555;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
input:invalid + label {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
input:focus {
  border-color: #2b96f1;
}
input:focus + label {
  color: #2b96f1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="user" required>
  <label for="user">user name</label>
</div>
  
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="password" required>
  <label for="user">password</label>
</div>
```

Если вы вдруг не знаете, как получить результат препроцессора на codepen, то вот скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]